# Code for getting the methods of a class using reflection (excluding system methods such as ToString(),Equals,Hasvalue etc..)

Tags: c#, wsdl, system.reflection

[image]

I am working on a wcf proxy generator which generates all the methods dynamically using c#.I am getting the below methods out of which i need only the selected first two.

GetMethods() in reflection returns all the methods(including ToString,Hasvalue,Equals etc) which are not needed for me(i.e Actual types which are defined by me)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify by which criteria you are choosing the methods (_the first two methods visible in the Debug Window_ is not very useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want methods which:

- are not getter/setter methods for use be properties
- are defined on the actual type, not base types
- do not have a return type of `void`

  ```
  var proxyType = proxyinstance.GetType();
  var methods = proxyType.GetMethods()
      .Where(x => !x.IsSpecialName) // excludes property backing methods
      .Where(x => x.DeclaringType == proxyType) // excludes methods declared on base types
      .Where(x => x.ReturnType != typeof(void)); // excludes methods which return void
  ```

All these conditions can also be combined into a single `Where` call:

```
var methods = proxyType.GetMethods().Where(x => 
    !x.IsSpecialName && 
    x.DeclaringType == proxyType && 
    x.ReturnType != typeof(void)
);
```

Comment: Thanks ,this is exactly what i needed